# Definite integral of trig function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I'm looking for some assistance on the following problem:

Let
$$ T(x) = \int_{4r^3}^{4} tsin(t^3)dt $$

Find $$T'(r)$$

I'm struggling to find the antiderivative of the sine function, particularly as it takes a cube as input.  I'm not sure how to 'reverse chain' these functions - could someone please provide some assistance as to how to begin disecting this problem?

Thanks.

**Update:**

From my calculations, I get

$$ T'(r) = \frac{d}{dr} \int_{4r^3}^{4} tsin(t^3)dt  = r^3sin(4r^3) (12r^2)$$
$$ T'(r) = 48r^5sin(4r^3)$$

Is any of this making sense?

Comment: In the first line of $T'(r)$, isn't it $\int \dots = \color{red}{4}r^3 \sin \left (4r^3 \right ) \left ( 12 r^2 \right )$. Then the result is correct I think.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Do not look for the antiderivative and remember the fundamental theorem of calculus. The derivative of $$\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t) dt=f\Big(b(x)\Big) b'(x)-f\Big(a(x)\Big) a'(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that
$$\int_a^b f(x)\, dx = \int_a^c f(x)\, dx + \int_c^b f(x)\, dx$$
and apply the fundamental theorem of calculus along with the chain rule.